# Associate name and id to an input box

Tags: java, html, spring, jsp

I have a text box in Jsp where I use Spring tags. I want to show the name of a student but associate the id too. At the moment I can only associate the name:

```
<form:input id="myexample" path="student" value="{student.name}"/>
```

What I wanna do is similar to what I can do with a SELECT:

```
<form:select id="myselect" path="student">
    <c:forEach items="${studentList}" var="student">
        <form:option value="${student.id}" label="${student.name}"></form:option>
    </c:forEach>
</form:select>
```

I would like to send the ID to the "path" but show the name.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to associate a hidden field to your userId as follows:

```
<form:input path="student" value="{student.name}"/>
<form:hidden path="student" value="{student.id}"/>
```

In the first you show the name of the user, and in the second one you hold the userId